# Python not looping correctly

Tags: python, loops

I have a problem with Python not properly looping over the lines in a file.  In the first block it loops over the lines properly and displays each line in the file.  However in the second block it only does the first line of the file and then stops.  The output of block 2 should be the same but it is not.  It is driving me crazy.

```
BLOCK-1
f = open(filename, 'r')
for line in f:
    print line,
f.close()
```

.

```
BLOCK-2
f = open(filename, 'r')
for line in f:
    match = re.search(r'^(.*)$', line)
    if match:
        print match.group(1)
    else:
        return "DOES NOT MATCH"
```

Comment: `return` means that you use block of code inside function?

Comment: `return` will exit the function immediately, as soon as the match fails for any line...

Comment: @nneonneo, this re should match any single line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your block-2 code has a return statement. Any line that will not match your regex will break the loop.

Comment: Thanks...I completely overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't mean `print "DOES NOT MATCH"`?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the `regex` is not matching the second line somehow

It can be helpful to print out the thing that didn't match, so you can work out why not

```
f = open(filename, 'r')
for line in f:
    match = re.search(r'^(.*)$', line)
    if match:
        print match.group(1)
    else:
        print repr(line), "DOES NOT MATCH"   # <--- Just add this line
        return "DOES NOT MATCH"
```